# Geometrically viewing matrices and matrix substraction

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a vector valued function defined over a plane, we can think of an arrow based at each point on the input plane. Suppose instead that we had a matrix valued function, that is it defines a matrix for each point in the domain, could we get a similar visualization to how we do for vector fields? Could there be something similar to a paralleogram law for matrix subtraction defined etc etc?

Example of matrix valued function:

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} u(x,y) & v(x,y) \\ p(x,y) & q(x,y)\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What kind of example do you mean? @MyMolecules

Comment: Have a look @MyMolecules

Comment: You can certainly think about such a function as a vector field. The catch is that for the visualization to be literally accurate, you would need the arrow to be $m \cdot n$-dimensional (where the matrix has size $m \times n$). So, for a $2\times 2$ matrix-valued function, you would need 4-dimensional arrows.

Comment: I don't quite get it, how are matrices also arrows? @BenGrossmann

Comment: A matrix can be thought of as an arrow in the same way that any list of numbers can be thought of as an arrow: interpret each entry as one of the coordinates of the arrow head, where the arrow emanates from the origin.